# Round Robin using Elixir

Tags: elixir, load-balancing, round-robin

I started learning **Elixir** and I was also looking for load balancing strategies. One of them is **Round Robin** and I have to implement it in a project. Yet, I haven't found too much resources on implementing Round Robin using Elixir.
Could someone provide some **examples** or **explanation** on how to do this(can be simple examples with some processes and a supervisor)? Or some **hints**. Any information on this is welcomed.

Comment: Probably you  can find something here: https://andrealeopardi.com/posts/process-pools-with-elixirs-registry/

Answer (score 1):

When I do not know how to do something in Elixir and cannot find any examples online, I usually look at how it was done in Erlang.

You could take a look at [Erlpool](https://github.com/silviucpp/erlpool), an Erlang round-robin load balancer for Erlang processes based on ETS